# Why does my Bash script work from command line but not when called from PHP?

Tags: php, linux, bash

I'm writing a script in bash run by PHP, which is supposed to show information about Linux (I'm getting hostname, kernel, load average, processor, memory). The output looks like this:

[image: screen]

I have a problem with showing 3 pieces information:

1. Number of logged users.
2. The number of packages.
3. Name and IP address of the network adapter.

I have a command that works on command line (of course with out shell_exec etc.), but not when I use PHP:

```
Ad 1. $usersononline=shell_exec('who -u | wc -l'); # show 0

Ad 2. $numbers_rpm=shell_exec('rpm -qa | wc -l'); # show nothing

Ad 3. $nic_info=shell_exec('ip -f inet -o -addr | awk \'{print $2 \":\" $4}\''); # show nothing
```

```php
function sys() {
    echo "<h3><b>System</br></b></h3>";
    $hostname1=exec('cat /etc/hostname');
    $os=exec('cat /etc/*-release | sed -n \'1p\'');
    $kernel=shell_exec('uname -r');
    $uptime=shell_exec('uptime -p');
    $lastboot=shell_exec('uptime -s');
    $useronline=shell_exec('who -u | wc -l');
    $date_time=shell_exec('date');
    $numbers_rqm=shell_exec('rpm -qa | wc -l');


    echo  "Hostname:  $hostname1<br>";
    echo  "OS:   $os</br>";
    echo "Kernel:    $kernel</br>";
    echo "Uptime:    $uptime</br>";
    echo "Last boot: $lastboot</br>";
    echo "User online:  $useronline</br>";
    echo "Server datetime: $date_time</br>";
    echo "Instaled packages: $numbers_rpm</br>";
}
sys();
```

Comment: You define `$numbers_rqm` but then echo `$numbers_rpm`, they are different. `$useronline` will show `0` if there are no logged in users. Be sure to have at least one user logged in.

Comment: I change $numbers_rpm  but still 0, $useronline too. Maybe php can't understand steam '|', because uptime -s is running?

Comment: The `who -u | wc -l` works fine on an Ubuntu server, don't have a CentOS to test the `rpm` command. I don't think it is the `|` that is causing trouble, but you can test removing it and just outputting the `who -u`, or just try something like `echo exec('w');`.

Comment: Ok I now what's wrong - selinux, when I disabled an reboot system, script show users and rpm packages:)

Comment: Glad you find the answer! You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).